# What should I call the person who translates the subtitle? Author or Translator?

Tags: nouns

I want to know in web, If someone translated a subtitle (translate a language to another language) What should I call this person, Author or Translator or .. ?

Comment: Are you talking about somebody who translates one subtitle into a subtitle of a different language, or are you talking about somebody who translates something original (I assume speech) into a subtitle of a different language in the first place? (I don't *think* it would make a difference to an answer, but the particular context could be useful.)

Comment: Yeah who translate some language to another language

Comment: "[W]ho translates [a] language to another language" ~ a translator?

Comment: Yeah That is my question should i call them "Translator" or "Author" ?

Comment: Is this question about the subtitle**s** in foreign-language films? In that sense, the word is almost never used in the singular.

Comment: It's not translated **a** subtitle. It's translated the **subtitles**.

Answer (score 2):

A person who turns something in one language into another is a **translator**.

An author is a person who *creates* a written work.

That is not to say that translators are not "creative". There is an art to a good translation. Rendering the meaning or intent of something into a different language is not an exact science, and translators are often given create credit for their artistic rendering into a another language. There is a legal sense in which a translator may be the "author" of a translated work for copyright purposes.

If a person is taking the words spoken in a work and rendering them as subtitles in another language then they are definitely the **translator**. They might be called "the author of the subtitles" but you absolutely must use the whole phrase "author of the subtitles" to avoid confusion with the author of the work. In credits you usually see "subtitles by.." which also avoids confusion.

Comment: Somebody who creates subtitles as part of the software authoring process is the creator and author *of the subtitles*. Your answer is too simplistic, missing many possible subtleties and interpretations of the language used to describe the various scenarios.

Comment: @JasonBassford Generally, speaking subtitles are this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtitles way before they are anything to do with writing software i.e. programming.

Answer (score 1):

Let's not confuse the profession of translator with what a translator translates.

Translators translate all sorts of things. Though one can specify as in **legal translator, technical translator, literary translator, subtitle translator, one does not always do this. Many translators (such as myself) translate an array of subject matter and forms, and,therefore, I would not use a qualifier for myself such as subtitle translator.
Others limit themselves to just one area. However, "subtitle translator" as a description is fine but not as a professional title.

Though it is correct, it is limited unless one is referring, for a reason, to the person who subtitled a particular movie or program. In movies, when credited, the credit should just read: translator.

For example, an architect designs and build structures. Though one can be a residential architect, one generally would not specify that as a title.

By the way, when you translate subtitles, if you are **lucky**, they give you the script but that is not always the case. When they don't, you have to listen over and over to the dialogues or oral text and then type your translation into the subtitling software. Translation of dialogue is not as easy as it might seem to the inexperienced. There are some Netflix movies with poor subtitle translation into English, because the translators simply do not know English well enough to do a good job. Often, it may be because the language is spoken by a small population (Finnish, for example) and there is just no native English speaker translator who does that language.

Translators are not the writers of the subtitles. The script writers are the authors.

[I am not giving any references as this is what I do for a living (translation) and, therefore, am my own reference, so to speak.]

Answer (score -1):

### Basic answer

Depending on how you look at it, as well as the specific context, the person could be described as one, the other, or both:

- I am the translator for these subtitles.
- I am the author of these subtitles.
- I acted as both translator and author in the creation of these subtitles.

The following definitions are from Merriam-Webster, and they describe the verbs from which the nouns are formed.

---

[**Translate**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/translator):

> **1 a** : to turn into one's own or another language
> **1 b** : to [transfer](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/transfer) or turn from one set of symbols into another : [TRANSCRIBE](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/transcribe)
> **1 c(1)** : to express in different terms and especially different words : [PARAPHRASE](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/paraphrase)
> **1 c(2)** : to express in more comprehensible terms : [EXPLAIN](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/explain), [INTERPRET](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/interpret)

[**Author**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/author):

> : to be the author of : [WRITE](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/write)
> // a writer who has *authored* several best sellers

---

From this, there are several possible scenarios—and I'll base them on speech in one language and the creation of subtitles in a different language.

I am only the translator in the following scenarios:

- I am listening to one language, and I'm telling somebody else what is being said in a different language.
- I am listening to one language, and I am writing down the words in a different language—but I am not actually creating subtitles.
  **Note**: In original-language movie or TV credits (where there are no subtitles), this role would be listed under "story by."

I am only the author in the following scenarios:

- Somebody is telling me what the words being spoken mean in a different language, and I am creating subtitles in the other language.
- I am looking at written words, and I am creating subtitles out of those words.
  **Note**: In original-language movie or TV credits (where there are no subtitles), this role would be listed under "screenplay by."

However, I can be both the translator *and* the author in the following scenario:

- I am listening to one language, and I am creating subtitles in another language.

---

Note that it's possible for certain combined senses of *translate* to give an implicit understanding of *author* at the same time. In that sense, it's possible to simply say that I'm *a translator*, and it will be assumed that I'm also *an author*. But that would only be understood from context.

---

### Distinguishing roles from credits

To address a comment, note how I started this answer. I said "depending on how you look at it."

My use of roles in this answer does not supplant the idea of either *screenwriter* or *story by* credits in movies or TV shows. Those credits would still remain. Movies and TV shows often have multiple credits for the writing team.

But in the specific context of subtitles, the people responsible for creating the subtitles would get their own additional credits. They would likely be listed under *subtitles by*. That does not discount their individual *roles* of translator and author with respect to those subtitles.

Finally, note that while books are also translated, that medium doesn't have subtitles. There is no speech with captions that fit visually on top. It's the entire text of the book that's translated. In the publishing industry, the author maintains the role of author, and the translator (and author of the translation) gets a credit as translator.

With respect to books, note again that the person responsible for the subtitles only gets a *credit* of translator (because the original text was not their own). But that still doesn't discount the fact that they could have filled the *roles* of both translator and author of the different-language text specifically.

As such, there is a distinction, certainly legally, between the credit given for translated work and the roles actually performed by the people doing that work.

Comment: Are you sure about this? It would strike me as not only misleading, but fraudulent, if a translator of movie subtitles ever called himself an author. It may be true that creating subtitles involves some steps that are in addition to actual translating, but that doesn't change the fact that **the** author of what appears in the subtitles is the screenwriter. You would presumably never call a translator of a book its author, so why would it be different for subtitles?

Comment: @jsw29 Remember the specific context of this question. It's not talking about somebody writing a book. It's talking about converting speech into subtitles for a movie or TV show. In that particular context, the person who actually uses the computer equipment to get the words into place would still be considered the *subtitle* author. In the credits, there would still be distinct credits for ***screenwriter***, ***story by*** (those can be distinct), and ***subtitles by*** (although I've never actually seen such a credit, the idea remains).

Comment: This is absolutely wrong. A person who takes words of a work (spoken or written) and turns them into another language is never the author of the work.

Comment: You say "I am listening to one language, and I am writing down the words in a different language—but I am not actually creating subtitles." makes you a translator but "Somebody is telling me what the words being spoken mean in a different language, and I am creating subtitles in the other language." makes you the author. What is the difference between the two? Are you saying it makes a difference whether you actually type your words into the machine that shows the subtitles, or whether you get someone else to do that

Comment: @DJClayworth A *verbatim* copy and paste might not assign authorship to you (although it still might depending on your sense of "author"), but if someone who speaks both languages doesn't speak the translated language well, and you have to paraphrase the translated version they gave you, then you would still be considered the author of the subtitles, simply using the translation as your source material. You are confusing the specific context of subtitle creation with translation in publishing.

Comment: Given that it is nowadays customary to give credits in films even to those who performed purely mechanical, nonartistic task in their production, such credits could indeed be given to those who did the work of making the subtitles, by some phrase like 'subtitles by . . .'. One would, however, still not use the word *author* in doing so. This is analogous to the fact that one may sometimes see credits like 'catering provided by . . .' or 'legal services provided by . . .', but one wouldn't say that the caterers or the lawyers are the authors of anyhting.

Comment: @jsw29 That's confusing credit with role. Just as job titles do not necessarily reflect what you actually do. It's similar to the difference between a proper name and a common noun.

Comment: There are no authors of subtitles. There are script writers....and subtitle translators. Clearly, no one here so far besides myself has actually done this work...

Comment: @JasonBassford There is absolutely no sense of the word "author" that would apply to something you cut and paste.

Comment: Hey! Don't stop answering posts because of a minor mishap and a disagreement with a mod.  Come back, EL&U needs you.

Comment: I don't see why this answer is downvoted so severely, or, frankly, at all. While I've had differences with @JasonBassford in the past, here he has phrased his argument carefully and explained the circumstances sufficiently in my view. If you limit the scope of "author" to the things this answer encompasses, I think it holds up. +1